# understanding the repeat function in Scheme

Tags: scheme

The code to repeat a function in Scheme is the following:

```
(define (repeat f n)
  (if (= n 1)
      f
      (lambda (x) (f ((repeat f (- n 1)) x)))))
```

But I don't manage to understand how the recursion here works with the lambda(x) and so on.

Can someone explain this with an example like (repeat f 3)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the substitution method and working "upwards":

```
(repeat f 1)
--> f
```

which is equivalent to `(lambda (x) (f x))`, if `f` is a unary function.

And then,

```
(repeat f 2)
--> (lambda (x) (f ((repeat f 1) x)))
--> (lambda (x) (f (f x)))
```

and

```
(repeat f 3)
--> (lambda (x) (f ((repeat f 2) x)))
    [through name change in the "inner" lambda]
--> (lambda (x) (f ((lambda (y) (f (f y))) x)))
    [through ((lambda (y) (f (f y))) x) --> (f (f x))]
--> (lambda (x) (f (f (f x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to realize is that this `repeat` function doesn't actually call `f` `n` times. It *returns* a new function that will call `f` `n` times. You can see this in the base case: when `(= n 1)`, it simply returns `f`, it doesn't execute `(f)`.

`(repeat f (- n 1))` calls `repeat` recursively to get a function that calls `f` one less time. `lambda` is then used to construct a new function that calls this new function and then calls `f` to make the total `n` calls.